# Change \rightmark to show last header defined

Tags: sectioning, formatting

How can I change the default behaviour of `\rightmark` to display the last defined section before the current page. The default behaviour appears to be the last defined section before the current page **IF** there are no new sections on the current page.

For example, the following produces a sample document with the default behaviour of `\rightmark`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum :)}
\section{Paragraphs 1 - 5}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Paragraphs 6 - 10}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Paragraphs 11 - 15}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

It looks a bit like this

[image]

I would like to make it look a bit more like this. Notice the header now references the last defined section

[image]

Comment: latex uses `\firstmark` and `\botmark` but you want `\topmark`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the comment. I managed to get it working with that information. Would you agree with the approach I took in the answer to achieve the result or is there a better way?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks again for the advice, but do you know why `\topmark` might be prefixed by `CONTENTS`? I posted a new question about it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448902/92999). I appreciate any help you can give

Answer (score 1):

Credits to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) for pointing me to `\topmark`

---

As mentioned before, this can be achieved by using `\topmark`. However, `\topmark` returns the chapter as part of the value. So this can be got around by "silencing" the `\chaptermark`.

In my case, I used

```
%Header / Footer info
\pagestyle{fancy}

%Change commands so when `topmark` is used, the last defined section before the current page is used
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}} %Uncomment this line if you don't like numbers

%Define the header / footer
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\topmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```