# How do I choose which subsection appears in the header?

Tags: titles

Can I write a command so LaTeX chooses the subsection which covers most of the page to be in the header? For example, see the image below.

[image]

How can I make it so that the header displays Section 2.2 rather than Section 2.3? I am currently using this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\lhead{\textit{\leftmark}}
\rhead{\textit{\rightmark}}
\rfoot{\textit{Page \thepage}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\xdef\leftmark{\thesection\quad#1}\xdef\rightmark{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\xdef\rightmark{\thesubsection\quad#1}}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: First and last are more meaningful concepts than "most of the page". You may need to swap back and forth between normal and revised \sectionmark and \subsectionmakr.  A full MWE would be useful.

Comment: @JohnKormylo How much more code should I add?

Comment: Your example should be able to be compiled so that the output exhibits the problam you describe, so it should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.  You can use `lipsum` to fill in dummy text. including enough `\subsection` entries to make the transition clear.  You will need to generate two pages, and maybe three, depending on whether the headers on left and right pages are different.  Or maybe this can help: [Change /rightmark to show last header defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448862)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done

Comment: Not quite.  To compile this successfully, it's also necessary to know the document class and any necessary packages.  It looks like `book` with a header-formatting package, but it's much better not to have to guess.

Comment: The document class is ```article```.

Comment: I'm not a user of `fancyhdr` so I am interpreting what it says in the user manual.  I think that replacing `\rightmark` by `\toprightmark` should have the desired result.  The distinction between `\topmark` (the desired condition) and `\firstmark` is what is important, but the documentation is a bit sparse on specifics (i.e., no prose description, only code).

Comment: That didn't help. Also, I have another query. My current code (in particular, ```\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\xdef\leftmark{\thesection\quad#1}\xdef\rightmark{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\xdef\rightmark{\thesubsection\quad#1}}```) cause an error if I use ```\mathcal``` in the subsection titles. Do you know how I can fix this?